# What does & and * denote in a helm template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

What does & and * denote in a helm template?

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/templates/chrome-node-deployment.yaml#L7

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/templates/chrome-node-deployment.yaml#L25

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "seleniumGrid.chromeNode.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels: &chrome_node_labels //**& here**
    app: selenium-chrome-node
    app.kubernetes.io/name: selenium-chrome-node
    {{- include "seleniumGrid.commonLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- with .Values.chromeNode.labels }}
      {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.customLabels }}
      {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.chromeNode.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-chrome-node
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: *chrome_node_labels // **star here **
      annotations:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the usage of YAML anchors, but I remember it would result in an error if used directly in the Helm templates. I guess they might be doing a second rendering here, where the YAML is parsed first.

**[YAML anchors](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/)**

Anchors and aliases. There are 2 parts to this:

- The anchor `&` which defines a chunk of configuration
- The alias `*` used to refer to that chunk elsewhere

So in the example below we use &build-test to define a step entity, which has several lines for reuse, and the alias *build-test to reuse it.

```yaml
definitions: 
  steps:
    - step: &build-test
        name: Build and test
        script:
          - mvn package
        artifacts:
          - target/**

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step: *build-test
    main:
      - step: *build-test
```

[anchors-and-aliases](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#anchors-and-aliases)

Comment: Thank you so much, now i can understand this concept . Yes , this will rendered by template engine - resulting in final k8s manifest.